# Element not found in a sub-iframe - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, iframe

Im having trouble while trying to click on a particular tab which is inside a "sub-iframe".
I guess that problem is related to that.

Mainly, i clicked on a button from an iframe and it redirects me to a second form:

```
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    WebDriverWait wait994234 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(100));
    WebElement iframe2342 = wait994234.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ebx-legacy-component")));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe2342);
    WebDriverWait wait9942332434 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(100));
    WebElement iframe2342432 = wait9942332434.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ebx_SubSessioniFrame")));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe2342432);
```

i used `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` right after when i click on the first buttom from iframe#1 (the parent) and again, i called the parent iframe and the second iframe (the child iframe)

The problem is that i wont be able to click on the tab because it always says:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: ebx_generatedId_100 (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

```
    WebDriverWait wait11020 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    WebElement accionesButton2 = wait11020.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ebx_generatedId_100")));
    JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor23 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jsExecutor23.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", accionesButton2);
```

The button has this:

`<em><span id="ebx_generatedId_100">Categories</span></em>`

I tried SO MANY TIMES

Comment: Before worrying about anything else fix your problem with clicking `id="ebx_generatedId_100"`. Run the test and debug your code, put a breakpoint just before where you are trying to click the span, and see what is going wrong.

Comment: Can you add the HTML element of the iFrame you are switching to?